# Can't restore model immediately after it's saved

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to immediately restore a model I just saved for debugging purposes but I end up getting the following error all the time:

```
venv2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py:636: RuntimeWarning:

Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "src/python/kmer/learning.py", line 269, in <module>
    TensorflowTrainingJob.launch(resume_from_reduce = c.resume_from_reduce)
  File "src/python/kmer/learning.py", line 66, in launch
    job.execute()
  File "kmer/map_reduce.py", line 71, in execute
    self.distribute_workload()
  File "kmer/map_reduce.py", line 107, in distribute_workload
    self.run_batch(self.batch[index])
  File "kmer/map_reduce.py", line 121, in run_batch
    batch[track] = self.transform(batch[track], track)
  File "src/python/kmer/learning.py", line 110, in transform
    saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.join("model save location")))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'restore'
```

Seems like the model has not been completely saved by the time I try to restore it. Here is the code:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for epoch in range(5):
        o, c = session.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: X, y: Y})
    saver.save(session, "model save location")
time.sleep(10)
graph = tf.Graph()
session = tf.Session(graph = graph)
with graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model save location")
    saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("model save location")))
```

I've tried adding calls to `sleep` in between just in case the save operation is async but that doesn't seem to help.

The exact same codes work when run later as part of a different script so there definitely has to be some timing issues.

Comment: Looks like `tf.train.import_meta_graph("model save location")` is returning a None object, maybe you should check the location of your model. Otherwise, did you try to use the same Saver  as follow : `saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), tf.train.latest_checkpoint("folder path")))`

Comment: Furthermore, the ''model save location'' must be the exact '.meta' file you want to load. Like in the TensorFlow example: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph

Comment: @AnthonyD'Amato The path is definitely okay, I spent an ample time making sure of that. Furthermore, if I run the restore part later, as I would normally do in my pipeline, I no longer get such an error.

Comment: @DarthPaghius Just to say, I cannot replicate your error with a toy model under python 3.6.5, tensorflow 1.8.0 (even without long sleep). How complicate (no. of parameters?) is your model? Or can you repeat the problem with toy model, suggesting it's actually not because your model takes longer time to save?